# Case statement for formatting conditionally

Tags: formatting, ms-access-2010, conditional-statements

I'm attempting to apply some conditional formatting to a field in an Access 2010 report, the condition is fairly straightforward in that I'm adding a specific number of days to a date and changing a font color. However the number if days I want to add depends on another value on the report a frequency field.

So I'm trying to write something along the lines of:

```
Select Case [frequency]

Case 12
do the formatting 

Case 6
do the formatting 

Case 3 
do the formatting
```

Is this possible using the expression builder for conditional formatting in Access 2010??

Comment: You have to add a number of conditions that matches your various cases. Conditional formatting expressions must always evaluate to true or false.

Comment: i realise that not sure my origina post was particularly clear what I need to do is change the conditions depending on a value in the Frequency field, so if the frequency is 12 months I have one set of conditions if the frequency is six months I'd have another set of conditions etc

Comment: Then your conditions have to be `Frequency=12 AND ...` Use 'Expression Is' instead of 'Field values is' as the type of condition.